# Can a Kraus representation act as the identity on any operator?

Tags: mathematics, quantum-operation, textbook-and-exercises, kraus-representation

In the textbook “Quantum Computation and Quantum Information” by Nielsen and Chuang, it is stated that there exists a set of unitaries $U_i$ and a probability distribution $p_i$ for **any** matrix A,

$$\sum_i p_i U_i A U_i^\dagger =tr(A) I/d,$$

where $d$ is the dimension of the Hilbert space. (This is on page 517; Exercise 11.19; equation (11.85)) The left-hand side is a Kraus representation given A.

But is this possible for a general non-diagonalizable (i.e. non-normal) matrix A? For a normal matrix A, I found it is indeed the case.

Comment: The wording of the question is not crystal clear, but it should be understood that the unitary matrices and probabilities may not depend on $A$, they may only depend on the dimension $d$. Once you know, for a given choice of these unitary matrices and probabilities, that the equation is true for all normal matrices $A$, it follows that it is true for all matrices $A$ by linearity. For instance, every matrix $A$ can be written as $A = H + i K$ for $H$ and $K$ Hermitian.

Comment: Of course every matrix can be written as a sum of the Hermitian and the anti-Hermitian part. However, for each Hermitian (and hence normal) matrix, we need to choose a specific set of unitary matrices $U_i$ to make it proportional to the identity matrix. In case of the matrix $A$ has both $H$ and $K$, I think we need to take $U_i$ which makes the lefthand side for the both $H$ and $K$ are proportional to the identity simultaneously not individually. Is this always possible?

Comment: By the way, when I say that the "wording of the question is not crystal clear," I am referring to the exercise itself, not the question posted here.

Comment: The unitary matrices and probabilities can be taken to be independent of $A$. The exercise is essentially asking you to prove that the completely depolarizing channel is a mixed-unitary channel, which it certainly is.

Comment: Thanks, now I understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. (***Orthonormal operatorial bases and their completeness***) The main thing to keep in mind is that this is a result about *a type of channel*, not about specific states. Suppose $\operatorname{tr}(U_i U_j^\dagger)=\delta_{ij}$ for some set of matrices $U_i$.
   This is equivalent to $\sum_{k\ell}(U_i)_{k\ell} (U_j^*)_{k\ell}=\delta_{ij}$.
   If $U_i$ form a basis (*i.e.* there are $n^2$ of them), then we must also have
   $\sum_i (U_i)_{k\ell} (U_i^*)_{mn}=\delta_{km}\delta_{\ell n}$.

   For such choice of matrices we have, for *any* matrix $\rho$,
   $$\sum_i U_i \rho U_i^\dagger
   = \sum_{ijk \ell m} \lvert j\rangle\!\langle k\rvert\,\, (U_i)_{j\ell}(U_i^*)_{km} \rho_{\ell m}
   = \sum_{jk\ell m} \lvert j\rangle\!\langle k\rvert\,\, \delta_{jk} \delta_{\ell m}\rho_{\ell m}
   \\= \sum_{j\ell} \lvert j\rangle\!\langle j\rvert \,\, \rho_{\ell\ell} = \operatorname{tr}(\rho) I. $$

   Notice how the identity does not depend on what $\rho$ is. It can be an arbitrary operator. You can test it yourself with a nondiagonalisable matrix such as $\rho=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. It is a statement about the mapping $\rho\mapsto \sum_i U_i \rho U_i^\dagger$, not about $\rho$.

   Notice also that I did not use any assumption on the $U_i$. They need not be unitaries (indeed, they *cannot* be unitaries in my choice of normalisation). To get the same factor on the RHS, you need only modify the normalisation of the matrices to have $\operatorname{tr}(U_i U_j^\dagger)=\delta_{ij}/d$, and the rest follows.
2. (***Choi representation of completely depolarising channel***)
   Consider the linear map $\Phi(X)=\operatorname{tr}(X) I/d$. You can verify that it is a CPTP map and thus admits a Kraus decomposition.

   Its natural representation reads $K(\Phi)=|m\rangle\!\langle m|$, or in components,  $K(\Phi)_{ij,k\ell}=\delta_{k\ell}\delta_{ij}/d$, with $|m\rangle$ the maximally entangled state.
   The Kraus decomposition is then obtained as the spectral decomposition of the operator mapping $j\ell$ to $ik$. We thus want the spectral decomposition of the Choi operator $$J(\Phi)\equiv (\Phi\otimes I) (d\lvert m\rangle\!\langle m\rvert)=\frac1 d I\otimes I\equiv I/d.$$
3. (***Eigendecomposition of Choi representation***) The eigendecomposition of this operator is trivial: its eigenvalues are all equal to $1/d$, thus any orthonormal set of vectors will be a suitable set of eigenvectors. Write these as $\newcommand{\bs}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} \{\bs v_a\}_a$, so that $J(\Phi)\bs v_a=\frac1 d \bs v_a$ for all $a=1,...,d^2$.
   In terms of the natural representation, these satisfy
   $$\sum_{j\ell} K(\Phi)_{ij,k\ell}(\bs v_a)_{j\ell} = \frac1 d(\bs v_a)_{ik}
   \Longleftrightarrow K(\Phi) = \frac1 d \sum_a \bs v_a \otimes \bs v_a^\dagger.$$
   $$K(\Phi)_{ij,k\ell}=\frac1 d\sum_a (\bs v_a)_{ik}(\bs v_a^*)_{j\ell}.$$
   Defining the operators $A_a$ as $(A_a)_{ij}\equiv (\bs v_a)_{ij}$, or equivalently, $\operatorname{vec}(A_a)=\bs v_a$, we get the Kraus decomposition
   $$\Phi(X) =
   \operatorname{unvec}\Big(\underbrace{\frac{1}{d}\sum_a (A_a \otimes \bar A_a)}_{\equiv K(\Phi)}\operatorname{vec}(X)\Big) =
   \frac{1}{d}\sum_a A_a X A_a^\dagger. $$
   Note that the orthogonality of the vectors $\bs v_a$, $\langle \bs v_a,\bs v_b\rangle=\delta_{ab}$, translates into the orthogonality of the matrices $A_a$ in the $L_2$ norm: $\langle A_a, A_b\rangle\equiv\operatorname{tr}(A_a^\dagger A_b)=\delta_{ab}$.
   Note also that here $\{A_a\}_a$ are *not* the Kraus operators of the channel: in the standard notation, the Kraus operators are the renormalised operators $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt d}A_a\}_a$.

(***Finding Kraus decompositions made up of unitaries***) In the above, $A_a$ are not unitaries. However, the freedom in the choice of vectors $\bs v_a$, or equivalently the freedom in the choice of $A_a$, can be used to find a decomposition in terms of Kraus operators that are (proportional to) unitaries.
A basis of unitaries can be constructed *e.g.* using [clock and shift matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices). Have a look at ([Durt 2010](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.3348)), around page 10, and [these nice notes by Wheeler](https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Miscellaneous%20Math/Unitary%20Bases.pdf) (pdf alert), around page 12.

Comment: related https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4978/55

Comment: Thank you! It was really clear and now I got it.

Answer (score 3):

Since it hasn't been mentioned so far, and I think it's an interesting aspect: A weighted ensemble $(p_i,U_i)$ of unitaries in $U(d)$ such that
$$
\sum_i p_i U_i X U_i^\dagger = \operatorname{tr}(X) \mathbb{I}/d,
$$
is called a *weighted unitary 1-design*. If the weights can be chosen uniformly, i.e. $p_i \equiv 1/N$ where $N$ is the size of the ensemble, this reduces to the definition of a "normal" unitary 1-design.

There are many examples for unitary 1-designs:

1. Unitary 1-designs are exactly tight operator frames with frame constant $N/d$
2. In particular, any orthogonal operator basis of unitaries is a unitary 1-design, e.g. the Weyl operators
3. In fact any irreducible unitary representation of a group is a unitary 1-design, e.g. the Heisenberg-Weyl (=generalised Pauli) and Clifford group.
4. For any large enough Haar-random ensemble of unitaries there are weights such that the above equation holds with high probability.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be approached without regards to Kraus representations (even if the motivation is to prove the convexity of entropy) or whether A is a normal matrix or not. Rather, this is a feature of the choice of $\{ U_{j} \}$. In particular, there exists a choice such that their action is to ``coarse-grain'' all the information in a state.

Here's a single qubit example to illustrate my point: consider the set $p_{j} = \frac{1}{4}, U_{j} = \sigma_{j}$ for $j \in \{ 1,2,3,4 \}$, where, $\sigma_{j}$ are the Pauli matrices (with $\sigma_{0} = \mathbb{I}$). Then, its action on a single qubit is,
$$ \sum\limits_{j} p_{j} U_{j} \rho U^{\dagger}_{j} = \frac{1}{4} \left( \mathbb{I} \rho \mathbb{I} + \sigma_{x} \rho \sigma_{x}  + \sigma_{y} \rho \sigma_{y}  + \sigma_{z} \rho \sigma_{z}   \right) = \cdots = \operatorname{Tr}\left( \rho \right) \frac{\mathbb{I}}{2},$$
where the $\cdots$ can be evaluated using the anticommutativity of the Pauli matrices (Hint: use the relation $\sigma_{j} \sigma_{k} \sigma_{j} = - \sigma_{k}$ for $j \neq k$).

Now, since any matrix $A$ can be written as $A = H + iK$ for hermitian matrices $H,K$; and any hermitian matrix $H$ can be written as $H = H_{1} - H_{2}$ for positive semidefinite matrices, you can write $A  = H_{1} - H_{2} + i(K_{1} - K_{2})$. Rewriting each of the matrices as $H_{1} = \operatorname{Tr}\left( H_{1} \right) (\frac{1}{\operatorname{Tr}\left( H_{1} \right)} H_{1})$, we have that $\frac{1}{\operatorname{Tr}\left( H_{1} \right)} H_{1}$ is a density matrix and so the above result applies. Continuing this, you'll find, using the linearity of trace, that for the $2 \times 2$ case, the above unitaries give you $\mathrm{Tr}(A) \frac{\mathbb{I}}{d}$.

The generalization to $n \times n$ matrices is left as an exercise to the OP (where you need to find a set of unitaries analogous to the Pauli matrices).

Edit: One way to obtain the result in $d$ dimensions is to use the $d^2$ [Heisenberg-Weyl operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices) (or the finite dimensional representation of the Heisenberg-Weyl algebra). If $X(i)Z(j)$ is the $(i,j)$th operator then, we have, $\frac{1}{d^{2}} \sum_{i, j=0}^{d-1} X(i) Z(j) \rho Z^{\dagger}(j) X^{\dagger}(i)=\frac{\mathbb{I}}{d}$. See, for example, Page 176 of [this book](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1445).

Comment: Are you assuming the state $\rho$ is written in terms of the Pauli matrices? For a higher dimension, I found it very difficult to compute the commutation relation with unitaries and Hermitian matrices given in a quantum tomography for $\rho$. (I tried with the U(n) basis.) Nevertheless in some dimensions like 2^n dimensions, we can construct such a basis with tensor products of Pauli matrices.

Comment: One way to obtain the result in $d$ dimensions is to use the $d^2$ [Heisenberg-Weyl operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices) (or the finite dimensional representation of the Heisenberg-Weyl algebra). If $X(i)Z(j)$ is the $(i,j)$th operator then, we have, $\frac{1}{d^{2}} \sum_{i, j=0}^{d-1} X(i) Z(j) \rho Z^{\dagger}(j) X^{\dagger}(i)=\frac{\mathbb{I}}{d}$. See, for example, Page 176 of [this book](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1445).

Answer (score 2):

If it holds for hermitian matrices, it holds for all matrices due to linearity: Over $\mathbb C$, the hermitian matrices span the full matrix space.