# Quantum channels that commute with any unitary channel

Tags: quantum-operation, unitarity

Consider a quantum channel $\Phi$ that maps from density operators $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}_A)$ to itself, that commutes with any unitary channel $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}_A)$, i.e. $\Phi(\mathcal{U}(\rho))=\mathcal{U}(\Phi(\rho)),\,\,\forall\rho\in\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}_A)$.

Is there a general characterisation of such channels? (As far as I can think of it, $\Phi$ can either be a unitary channel or a depolarization channel. What are the other possibilities?)

Comment: This seems to me related to reference frame preserving maps https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/10/3/033023/pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference! @R.W Could you help point to the exact part where the relevant discussion is given?

Comment: The given answer is great, check it out. My reference is only an application of this idea of using commutations to define interesting classes of channels, therefore only of secondary relevance to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is, you're asking about the *commutant* of the representation $U\mapsto U(\cdot)U^\dagger$ of the unitary group $U(d)$. From a representation-theoretic point of view, the superoperators in the commutant are easy to characterize: By Schur's lemma, such an operator has to be proportional to the identity on every irrep of $U\mapsto U(\cdot)U^\dagger$.

These irreps are well-known and are given by the following orthogonal decomposition of the vector space of linear operators $L(\mathbb C^d)$:
$$
L(\mathbb C^d) = \langle \mathbb I \rangle \oplus \{\text{traceless operators}\}.
$$
The projection on $\langle \mathbb I \rangle$ is the *completely depolarizing channel*:
$$
\mathcal{D}(X) := \mathrm{tr}(X) \frac{\mathbb I}{d}.
$$
The projection on the traceless operators is simply $\mathrm{id}-\mathcal{D}$. Hence, every element $X$ in the commutant can be written as
$$
 X = a \mathcal{D} + b (\mathrm{id}-\mathcal{D}) = a' \mathcal{D} + b' \mathrm{id}.
$$
The latter decomposition is not orthogonal, but has to advantage to answer your question: The only quantum channels which commute with unitary channels are the *completely depolarizing channel* and the *identity channel*, and of course any convex combination of those.

For more details on the rep theory, see my answer here: [Why does the twirl of a quantum channel give a depolarizing channel?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23845/why-does-the-twirl-of-a-quantum-channel-give-a-depolarizing-channel/23846#23846)