# Are continuous probability distributions over quantum channels possible?

Tags: quantum-operation

I am not an expert in the subject and apologize in advance for a strange question and (possible) abuse of the terminology.

I have learned that any convex combination of quantum channels (CPTP maps, following another nomenclature) is a quantum channel, $T = \sum_{n=1} ^{M} p_i T_i$, $\sum_{n=1} ^{M} p_i = 1$. Here is the question:

Is it possible to introduce a continuous  probability distribution over a parametrized set of quantum channels? Then define an integral over the pdf (somehow) and and nominate the resulting quantum channel for the 'mean' of the set?

Answer (score 4):

Quantum channels describe stochastic events, so it should be completely legit to consider continuous sets of events. Integrating over a continuous set of quantum channels with some distribution give you a valid quantum channel, describing the "average" effect in some sense.

Here's an example. Consider an $X$-rotation of $90^\circ$ (*i.e.,* $\pi/2$-pulse) on a single qubit system,
\begin{equation}
X_{\pi/2} = \exp\left(-\frac{i}2\cdot\frac{\pi}2X \right).
\end{equation}
When implementing this pulse in experiment, due to imperfect control, the rotating angle might be something like $\pi/2+\delta$ instead of $\pi/2$, where $\delta$ is an independent random variable for every instance of realization of the pulse, satisfying certain distribution $p(\delta)$ such as a zero-mean Gaussian. In this case, the average effect of the experimental implementation of $X_{\pi/2}$ can be modeled as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal E(\rho) &=\int d\delta~p(\delta)~X_{\pi/2+\delta}\rho X_{\pi/2+\delta}^\dagger\\
&=\int d\delta~p(\delta)~\exp\left(-\frac{i}2\left(\frac{\pi}2+\delta\right)X \right)\rho\exp\left(\frac{i}2\left(\frac{\pi}2+\delta\right)X \right),
\end{aligned}
$$
which can be understood as integration over the continuous parameterized set of unitary quantum channels $\mathcal E_\delta(\rho) \equiv X_{\pi/2+\delta}(\rho)X^\dagger_{\pi/2+\delta}$ according to $p(\delta)$. Note that, $\mathcal E$ is no longer a unitary channel.

*PS:* By expanding $\rho$ in the eigenbasis of Pauli $X$ you can simplify the expression of $\mathcal E$.

Comment: Thank you, Senrui. Eventhough mixed-unitary channels are a special kind of channels, you explanation answers my question. I am also thinking that the average channels (in general case) can be found, e.g., by using Choi-Jamiolkowski correspondence, from the corresponding parametrized sets. Spectral properties of 'averaged' channels are of a special interest to me

Answer (score 3):

Sure. A standard example of this is the use of "twirling operations": given a channel $\mathcal E$, one can define
$$\mathcal E_T(\rho) = \int dU\, U^\dagger\mathcal E(U\rho U^\dagger)U,$$
with the integral over the Haar measure over unitary operators. This is a convex combination of channels, hence $\mathcal E_T$ is a channel (which can be shown to always be a depolarising channel). See *e.g.* this classical [Nielsen 2002 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205035) using it (or rather, reviewing its [previous use by the Horodeckis in 1999](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9807091)).

See also this related post: *[Why does the twirl of a quantum channel give a depolarizing channel?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/23845/55)*

Comment: Thank you, giS. Do you know any example which is not a mixed-unitary channel?

Comment: @trurl why do you say that this is a mixed-unitary channel? Here $\mathcal E$ is arbitrary, so the channels $\rho\mapsto U^\dagger \mathcal E(U\rho U^\dagger)U$ are not unitary in general

Comment: such channels - defined as a convex combination of unitaries - are called "mixed-unitary channels" (see, e.g.,, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.03164.pdf, just a first reference I found). However, you are right, your example is not a mixed-unitary channel.

Comment: @trurl what "such channels" are you referring to? I know what mixed-unitary channels are, but I'm confused as to what's their relevance here

Comment: mea culpa. Sorry for the confusion, your example is what I needed. And of course, it is not a unitary-mixed channel, as you correctly pointed out.