# Prove that the twirling operation on a channel gives a decomposition $\int dU\, U^\dagger\mathcal E(U\rho U^\dagger)U=\alpha P+\beta Q$

Tags: quantum-operation, projection-operator, depolarizing-channel

The twirled operation of a quantum channel $\mathcal E$ is defined as
\begin{align}
\mathcal E_T(\rho)
&= \int dU U^\dagger \mathcal E(U \rho U^\dagger)U,
\end{align}
where the integral is over the normalized Haar measure $dU$.

Let $P$ be a one-dimensional projector, and $Q \equiv I − P$ be the projector onto the orthocomplementary space. Letting $V$ be block diagonal with respect to the spaces onto which $P$ and $Q$ project, we see that $V P V^\dagger = P$ and thus $V \mathcal E_T (P )V^\dagger = \mathcal E_T (P)$. How to prove that $\mathcal E_T(P) = \alpha P+ \beta Q$ for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

This result was in [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205035) by Nielsen.
[image]

Comment: please try to avoid using screenshots of text. The hinder readability and searchability of the post. You can use `> quote` blocks to quote text

Comment: Roughly speaking, $V\mathcal{E} _T\left( P \right) V^{\dagger}=\mathcal{E} _T\left( P \right) $ means $\mathcal{E} _T\left( P \right) $ commutes with $V$. Since $V$ can be any unitary as long as it's block diagonal w.r.t. spaces onto which $P$ and $Q$ project, $\mathcal{E} _T\left( P \right) $ can only be an identity in spaces which $P$ and $Q$ project. Think of this simple example: the only possibility that a matrix commutes with any unitary matrices is when it is proportional to the identity.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/23845/55, and links therein