# Find an operator-sum representation for a depolarizing channel acting on 2qubit

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, quantum-operation, kraus-representation

In Nielsen and Chuang (page:379), it shows how to represent a 1 qubit depolarizing channel in  operator-sum representation.
$$
    \mathcal{E}_1(\rho)=pI/2+(1-p)\rho
    =(1-3p/4)\rho+p/4(X\rho X+Y\rho Y+Z\rho Z)
$$

How to write a 2 qubit depolarizing channel in  operator-sum representation?

$$
    \mathcal{E}_2(\rho)=pI/4 +(1-p)\rho
$$

Comment: possible duplicate of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4978/55. See also https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/24522/55 and https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12909/55 for the expressions in the general case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2 qubit Hilbert space, $$I_{12}/4$$ can be written in the form
$$
    I_{12}/4=I_1/2\otimes I_2/2
$$

and
$$
    I_k/2 =\frac{1}{4} (\rho +X_k\rho X_k+Y_k\rho Y_k+Z_k\rho Z_k)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \mathcal{E}(\rho) = (1 - p) I \otimes I \rho I \otimes I + \sum_{i = 1}^{15} \frac{p}{16} A \otimes B \rho A \otimes B, $$ where $A \otimes B \in \{I, X, Y, Z\} \otimes \{I, X, Y, Z\} \backslash II$

Comment: This doesn't look trace preserving, you need $(1-15p/16)$ in the first term

Comment: Sure. That's the correct channel though minus the typo.