# Action of a channel on an "unphysical" state

Tags: quantum-operation, density-matrix

Suppose we are given a rule $\Phi$ which is completely positive and trace preserving operation takes an input qubit state $\rho$ to an output qubit state $\rho^\prime$ (as an example of such rule see equation (11) of [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9911079.pdf)). In other words, its input as well as output are valid density matrix (with unit trace). The rule does not tell us how what happens if input is not a valid density matrix.

One often encounters situations, for example, the Choi matrix

$$ \chi = 
\left( \mathbb{1} \otimes  \Phi  \right) |\tilde{\psi} \rangle \langle \tilde{\psi} | = \sum_{ij} |i\rangle \langle j| \otimes \Phi(|i\rangle \langle j|), $$
where $|\tilde{\psi} \rangle = |00\rangle + |11\rangle$ is maximally entangled state Bell state apart from a normalization factor (assuming $\Phi$ is a qubit operation).

Now $\Phi(|0\rangle \langle 0|)$ and $\Phi(|1\rangle \langle 1|)$ make perfect sense since both $|0\rangle \langle 0|$ and $|1\rangle \langle 1|$ are valid density matrices. But how about $\Phi(|i\rangle \langle j|)$ with $i\ne j$? Since  $|i\rangle \langle j|$ ($i\ne j$) is not a valide density matrix, we do not how $\Phi$ acts on it (remember we only have the rule $\Phi$ for valid density a matrix). Then how can one construct such quantities?

Comment: Related:https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28104/how-to-calculate-the-action-of-a-channel-on-part-of-a-quantum-state Mind the statement in the comment.

Comment: is this question actually related to the Choi? It seems to me like you're just asking whether/why it makes sense to consider the action of a generic channel on an operator that does not represent a physical state

Comment: @glS, you are right, and in particular it I am only concerned with this issue when it comes to  Choi matrix that we want to calculate for a map which is, by definition, defined for valid a density matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quantum channel sends states to states, which are positive semidefinite matrices. But it is a linear map. There's no problem in extending its action to all matrices by linearity, since every matrix is a linear combination of pure states with complex coefficients. It's even simpler to treat quantum channel as a map from all matrices to matrices.

Any matrix $A$ can be written as
$$
A = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^\dagger) + \frac{1}{2}(A - A^\dagger) 
= \frac{1}{2}(A+A^\dagger) - \frac{i}{2}(i(A - A^\dagger)).
$$

Matrices $(A+A^\dagger)$ and $i(A - A^\dagger)$ are Hermitian (here $A - A^\dagger$ is skew Hermitian). Thus they are linear combinations of pure states by spectral theorem. Hence $A$ is also a linear combination of pure states, say $A = \sum_i \mu_i \rho_i$, $\mu_i \in \mathbb{C}$. Then $\Phi(A) = \sum_i \mu_i \Phi(\rho_i)$.