How can the depolarizing channel, defined as $\mathcal E(\rho) = (1-p)\rho + p\frac{I}{2}$, be a linear quantum operation?
In Quantum Computing: From Linear Algebra to Physical Realizations it states that

A quantum operation maps a density matrix to another density matrix linearly

But let $\rho\in M_2$ be a density matrix and consider the Depolarizing Channel
$$
\mathcal E(\rho) = (1-p)\rho + p\frac{I}{2}
$$
How is this linear? We have that $$
\mathcal E(\rho_1 + \rho_2) = (1-p)(\rho_1 + \rho_2) + p\frac{I}{2} \neq (1-p)(\rho_1 + \rho_2) + 2p\frac{I}{2} = \mathcal E(\rho_1) + \mathcal E(\rho_2). 
$$
I'm trying to calculate the Choi Matrix, which my professor defines in the following way:
$C(\mathcal E) = (C_{ij})$ where $C_{ij} = \mathcal E(E_{ij})$ where $\{E_{ij} = |i\rangle\langle j|: i, j \in \{0,1 \}\}$ is the standard basis for $M_2$.
I do not understand the definition for the Choi matrix $C(\mathcal E)$; how can we plug in $E_{01}$ into $\mathcal E$ when $E_{01}$ is not a density matrix? My professor says it is first necessary to decompose $E_{01}$ as a linear combination of density matrices, but if $\mathcal E$ is linear, is that not pointless? We would get the same result. It only makes sense to talk about the Choi Matrix of a linear map (right?), so how can I be asked to calculate the Choi Matrix for the Depolarizing Channel?

@FDGod I added an explanation as to what I mean by $E_{12}$. I have the $\neq$ because the coefficients of the last term in the LHS and RHS don't match.

@JohnHippisley I have not seen this definition before, if I use the one in Eq. (1.20) of Gottesman's book (https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2024/cmsc858G/QECCbook-2024-ch1-13.pdf), the depolarizing channel is indeed linear.

possible duplicate of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/28445/55

This kind of problem seems to arise quite regularly ... maybe we should have a canonical answer (phrased broadly enough) and close as duplicates.

Does this answer your question? Depolarizing channel for $n$ qubits: why is there a trace term?

@JohnHippisley Your professor is wrong (or you quote them incorrectly) - there is no need to decompose this as a linear combination of density matrices.

The correct linear form of the depolarizing channel is
$$
\varepsilon(\rho) = (1-p)\rho + p\frac{I}{2}{\rm Tr}(\rho).
$$
For density matrices ${\rm Tr}(\rho)=1$, so you can usually see the form without the ${\rm Tr}$ part.
Since $\varepsilon$ is just a linear map between matrices you can use any matrix as an input, not just density matrices.
E.g.
$$
\varepsilon(E_{01}) = (1-p)E_{01}.
$$
BTW, any matrix is indeed a linear combination of density matrices, but with complex coefficients.
$$
E_{01} = (X + iY)/2 = (X+I)/2 + i(Y+I)/2 - (i+1)I/2.
$$

I see, so the $Tr(\rho)$ guarantees that $\varepsilon$ is linear when we consider any matrix as an input.
