Why is the Choi matrix I get for the depolarizing channel $\mathcal{E}(\rho) = (1 - p) \rho + p \frac{I}{2}$ different from what it shold be?
I'm currently trying to implement the depolarizing channel on qiskit. But, as I see in my calculation it doesn't match with the qiskit aer_noise.
So, for the Depolarizing Channel we got :
$$
\mathcal{E}(\rho) = (1 - p) \rho + p \frac{I}{2}
$$
Ant the choi matrix equation is:
$$
\Lambda_\mathcal{E} = (\mathcal{I} \otimes \mathcal{E})(|\Phi\rangle \langle \Phi|)
$$
So, this is the tricky part where i get lost, I know that the Choi matrix got the Channel acting in every ketbra on the base, so in this case, for a one qubit i got:
$$
\mathcal{E}(|0\rangle \langle 1|) = (1-p) |0\rangle \langle 1| + p/2 (|0\rangle \langle 0| + |1\rangle \langle 1|)
$$
$$
\mathcal{E}(|1\rangle \langle 0|) = (1-p) |1\rangle \langle 0| + p/2 (|0\rangle \langle 0| + |1\rangle \langle 1|)
$$
$$
\mathcal{E}(|0\rangle \langle 0|) = (1-p/2) (|0\rangle \langle 0|) + p/2 (|1\rangle \langle 1|)
$$
$$
\mathcal{E}(|1\rangle \langle 1|) = (1-p/2) (|1\rangle \langle 1|) + p/2 (|0\rangle \langle 0|)
$$
Sho, the Choi matrix for this channel would be
$$ \Lambda_\mathcal{E}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 - \frac{p}{2} & 0 & \frac{p}{2} & 1 - p \\
0 & \frac{p}{2} & 0 & \frac{p}{2} \\
\frac{p}{2} & 0 & \frac{p}{2} & 0 \\
1 - p & \frac{p}{2} & 0 & 1 - \frac{p}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$.
However, if I use the qiskit funciton aer.get_noise and later use the Choi(noise) i get the form :
$$ \Lambda_\mathcal{E}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 - \frac{p}{2} & 0 & 0 & 1 - p \\
0 & \frac{p}{2} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{p}{2} & 0 \\
1 - p & 0 & 0 & 1 - \frac{p}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$.
Can someone help me to understand why is the second form? Thanks.

possible duplicate of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/28445/55, and links therein

Your definition of the depolarizing channel is slightly off, it should read
$$
\mathcal E(\rho)=(1-p)\rho+p\,\boxed{{\rm tr}(\rho)}\frac I2\,.
$$
This extra term ${\rm tr}(\rho)$ is necessary for $\mathcal E$ to be a linear map (without it, the $0$ matrix would not be mapped to the $0$ matrix which would contradict linearity).
Of course if $\rho$ is a state, then ${\rm tr}(\rho)=1$ which recovers your definition. What changes—and what constitutes your extra terms causing the mismatch—is that the off-diagonal blocks of the Choi matrix read
$$
\mathcal E(|0\rangle\langle 1|)=(1-p)|0\rangle\langle 1|+p\,\underbrace{{\rm tr}(|0\rangle\langle 1|)}_{=\langle 1|0\rangle=0}\frac I2=\begin{pmatrix}0&1-p\\0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
so there are no diagonal terms, as output by qiskit.

Omg I completely miseed that part. Now it works as intended. Thanks for helping me! This term applies to any QC that is CPTP?

You're welcome! And yes, any (seemingly) constant term in the definition of any channel necessarily needs a factor ${\rm tr}(\rho)$ for the sake of linearity

Thank you again! Is there any book or paper that mentions it? I see its kinda obvious but, It will help me for my article.

I don't know of any work that references this fact in general for it is too vague, but if you're okay with a book where just the depolarizing channel is defined rigorously (i.e. with this trace factor) check, e.g., Definition 6.36 in Holevo's book "Quantum Systems, Channels, Information" (2012)

Thank you! Sorry to ask again but. Revisiting some lectures, there are some papers who mention that the Choi matrix is the way i mention here. But, there is the factor 1/d. Why qiskit and well, this matrix doesn't use the 1/d factor? $\frac{1}{d} \sum |i \geq \leq j|  \otimes \mathcal{E}  ( |i\geq \leq j |)$

That's the difference between the Choi matrix and the Choi state. The Choi matrix is defined as the action $({\rm id}\otimes\mathcal E)(|\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega|)$ on the unnormalized state $\Omega:=\sum_j|jj\rangle$ (i.e. without the $\frac1d$) whereas the Choi state includes that normalization factor to give a mapping between quantum channels and (valid) quantum states also known as the Choi-Jamiolkowski isomorphism. Mathematically these are equivalent, their use depends more on the physical problem you want to use it for
