# Deriving the choi matrix definition of the quantum depolarizing channel

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-operation, information-theory, depolarizing-channel

I was reading up on the quantum depolarizing channel ([Preskill's Notes](http://theory.caltech.edu/%7Epreskill/ph219/chap3_15.pdf)) ([stack exchaange explanation](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4980/9360)), and I'm failing to see how the form

\begin{align}
\sigma &= (\mathcal E \otimes \mathbb I)(|\Omega\rangle\langle \Omega|) = \sum_{ij} \mathcal E(|i\rangle\langle j|)\otimes  |i\rangle\langle j|\ 
\end{align}

gets simplified to:

$$
\sigma = \frac{p}{2D}\mathbb I\otimes \sum_{i}|i\rangle\langle i| +
(1-p)\frac1D \sum_{ij}|i\rangle\langle j|\otimes |i\rangle\langle j|\ .
$$

where then the first term becomes the identity. When I solve the same channel representation, I find the matrix looks like:

$$
\sigma = \frac{p}{2D}\mathbb I\otimes \sum_{ij}|i\rangle\langle j| +
(1-p)\frac1D \sum_{ij}|i\rangle\langle j|\otimes |i\rangle\langle j|\ .
$$

Where the first term isn't able to simplify into something as simple as the identity, but is of the form $$I_{2} + \sigma^{x}_{2}$$ where the subscript denotes that the operation is on the second qubit.

I can't seem to pinpoint the mistake in my derivation here, so any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For $\mathcal E(X)=p\mathrm{tr}(X)\,\frac{\mathbb I}{2}+(1-p)X$, then

$$\begin{align}
\sigma &= (\mathcal E \otimes \mathbb I)(|\Omega\rangle\langle \Omega|)\\
 &= \sum_{ij} \mathcal E(|i\rangle\langle j|)\otimes  |i\rangle\langle j|\ \\ 
&=\sum_{ij}\left[p\mathrm{tr}(|i\rangle\langle j|)\,\frac{\mathbb I}{2}+(1-p)|i\rangle\langle j|\right] \otimes |i\rangle\langle j| \\
&= \sum_{ij}\left[p\langle j|i\rangle\,\frac{\mathbb I}{2}+(1-p)|i\rangle\langle j|\right] \otimes |i\rangle\langle j| \\
&= \sum_{ij}p\delta_{ij}\frac{\mathbb I}{2} \otimes |i\rangle\langle j| +(1-p)|i\rangle\langle j| \otimes |i\rangle\langle j| \\
&=p\sum_{i}\frac{\mathbb I}{2} \otimes |i\rangle\langle i| + \sum_{ij}(1-p)|i\rangle\langle j| \otimes |i\rangle\langle j|
\end{align}$$

The term $\mathrm{tr}(|i\rangle\langle j|)$ is missing in your calculation I think.